# Formatting an XML File

Tags: php, simplexml, xmldocument

I currently am using `simplexml_load_file(file.xml)` to load an XML and `$xmlRoot->saveXML('file.xml')` to save an XML File,

The code does my goals but when ever I open the XML File where it saved, it always has either spaces from deleting nodes and/or very long lines of elements from adding nodes (1 parent element and all child elements in 1 line).

My question is how do I format it in a clean format via php code?
(I want something similar to C#'s `XMLDocument` class where it formats itself when saved)

My current XML File is similar to this:

```
<rootElement>

     <parentElement><childElement>data</childElement></parentElement>

     <parentElement><childElement>data</childElement></parentElement>
</rootElement>
```

I want it to become something like this:

```
<rootElement>
     <parentElement>
        <childElement>data</childElement>
     </parentElement>
     <parentElement>
        <childElement>data</childElement>
     </parentElement>
</rootElement>
```

It looks clean now, but i have quite a large XML File which has multiple child elements per parent element

Thanks and cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try to import the simpleXml into a DOMDocument, which offers some formatting options:

```
$simpleXml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$xmlDom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$xmlDom->formatOutput = true;
$xmlDom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xmlDom->loadXML($simpleXml->asXML());
echo $xmlDom->saveXML();
```

Regards,